# Get all path variables & query parameters including their type

Tags: java, spring, swagger, spring-restcontroller

Is there way how to obtain all path variables & request parameters (query parameters) including their type? I need given request parameters type (and not just String), because I'm forwarding such call via Spring WebClient and if e.g. boolean query parameter is send as String, then I get exception from target rest api.

```java
        final var url = new ApiPathAndQueryUrlBuilder() // my helper/wrapper for UriComponentsBuilder
                .addPathVariables(allPathVariables)
                .addQueryParameters(allRequestParams)
                .buildUrl("target/endpoint/path");

        return wmWebClient
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .onErrorMap(WebClientRequestException.class, ex -> new RestApiUnavailableException(ex,"some descriptive error")
                .block();
```

I was hoping that this can be achieved by adding `UriComponentsBuilder builder` as method parameter:

```java
    @Operation(value = "Get Example Data")
    @GetMapping("/data/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getExampleData(
            @ApiParam(value = "The ID of the data", required = true) @PathVariable Long id,
            @ApiParam(value = "A String query parameter") @RequestParam String queryParam,
            @ApiParam(value = "A boolean query parameter") @RequestParam boolean flag,
            UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    }
```

But queryParams & uriVariables have size 0

[image: Debug of UriComponentsBuilder]

So instead of this I used annotation & `Map<String,String>` as mentioned in Spring [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

> If the method parameter is Map<String, String> or MultiValueMap<String, String> and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.

```java
    @Operation(value = "Get Example Data")
    @GetMapping("/data/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getExampleData(
            @ApiParam(value = "The ID of the data", required = true) @PathVariable Long id,
            @ApiParam(value = "A String query parameter") @RequestParam String queryParam,
            @ApiParam(value = "A boolean query parameter") @RequestParam boolean flag,
            @PathVariable Map<String, String> allPathVariables,
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    }
```

But this brings another issue - such parameters are visible in Swagger (thus also in generated TS/Angular client).

And issue with not-preserved type is still there (for now I have `Map<String, Class>`, `.addQueryParameters(allRequestParams, Map.of())` where I'm "manually" adding all query parameters that are not `String` and doing conversion in my `ApiPathAndQueryUrlBuilder`, but this is "second source of truth" and error prone).

Comment: parameters are always String as the web doesn't know anything about types.